# Email sending in powershell

Tags: powershell

For some reason this function works fine on one computer but throws an error when copy/pasted on another computer

error

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At line:21 char:5
+     $smtp.send($message)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

function

```
function Send-ToEmail([string]$email, [string]$attachmentpath, [string]$subject, [string]$body){

    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $message.From = "alerts@somedomain.com"
    $message.To.Add($email)
    $message.Subject = $subject
    $message.Body = $body
    
    $attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachmentpath)
    $message.Attachments.Add($attachment)
    
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.somedomain.com", "587")
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("alerts@somedomain.com", "passwordhere")
    $smtp.send($message)
    
    $attachment.Dispose()
    }

Send-ToEmail  -email "recepient@somedomain.com" -attachmentpath "c:\temp\transfer.log" -subject "[SUCCESS] Data extracts" -body "Extracts were uploaded successfully!"
```

Comment: Your code works for me, check the powershell version of the device that isn't working and compare it with the working one.
Also check that you have whitelisted the other device, if you have blacklist/whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Send-ToEmail([string]$email, [string]$attachmentpath, [string]$subject, [string]$body){

    $fromaddress = "alerts@somedomain.com" 
    $smtpserver = "smtp.somedomain.com" 

    $message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
    $message.From = $fromaddress
    $message.To.Add($email)
    $message.IsBodyHtml = $True
    $message.Subject = $Subject 
    $attach = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachmentpath) 
    $message.Attachments.Add($attach) 
    $message.body = $body 
    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver) 
    $smtp.Send($message)
}

Send-ToEmail  -email "recepient@somedomain.com" -attachmentpath "c:\temp\transfer.log" -subject "[SUCCESS] Data extracts" -body "Extracts were uploaded successfully!"
```

Comment: SMTP server requires SSL and authentication, so I've added EnableSSL and credentials back and it throws the same error

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work because on one computer $message.Header and $message.HeadersEncoding are empty. On the computer where this script works both .Headers and .EncodingHeaders are populated automatically